# WKWebview crash with Application received signal 11 error

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I was using UIWebview before, and replace WKWbview on this version. Then I received a lot of error reports like this:

```
1 WebKit 0x18acddfe0 IPC::Connection::markCurrentlyDispatchedMessageAsInvalid() + 4
2 WebKit 0x18ad646e8 WebKit::NetworkProcessProxy::didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, WebCore::AuthenticationChallenge const&, unsigned long long) + 108
3 WebKit 0x18ad668b0 voidIPC::handleMessage<Messages::NetworkProcessProxy::DidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge, WebKit::NetworkProcessProxy, void (WebKit::NetworkProcessProxy::*)(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, WebCore::AuthenticationChallenge const&, unsigned long long)>(IPC::Decoder&, WebKit::NetworkProcessProxy*, void (WebKit::NetworkProcessProxy::*)(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, WebCore::AuthenticationChallenge const&, unsigned long long)) + 108
4 WebKit 0x18acdd65c IPC::Connection::dispatchMessage(std::__1::unique_ptr<IPC::Decoder, std::__1::default_delete<IPC::Decoder> >) + 164
5 WebKit 0x18acdfe54 IPC::Connection::dispatchOneMessage() + 232
6 JavaScriptCore 0x185ebff44WTF::RunLoop::performWork() + 172
7 JavaScriptCore 0x185ec021cWTF::RunLoop::performWork(void*) + 36
8 CoreFoundation 0x1815f542c___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
9 CoreFoundation 0x1815f4d9c___CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
10 CoreFoundation 0x1815f29a8___CFRunLoopRun + 744
11 CoreFoundation 0x181522da4_CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
12 GraphicsServices 0x182f8d074_GSEventRunModal + 100
13 UIKit 0x1877ddc9c_UIApplicationMain + 208
14 iTouzi 0x1001792b8_main (main.m:17)
15 libdyld.dylib0x18053159c_start + 4
```

Now I don't know how to analyze this crash, does anyone know how to fix this crash?